# How to explain what amped means?

Tags: meaning

I have a website that classifies Spotify Playlists:

http://organizeyourmusic.playlistmachinery.com

And after the classification, it gets this:

[image]

I am a native spanish speaker, when I search for the translation, it makes no sense to me in the terms of music.

Comment: I'm glad you've received an answer, but please be aware that our site prefers questions that *show evidence of research*. The ending "-ed" suggests the word might be a past participle, in which case the root verb would be "amp". If you'd looked this up in a dictionary it would have provided the solution for you. For future questions, you might consider our sibling site [ell.se]. :-)

Comment: @Chappo I'd be surprised if looking this up would give a _definitive_ answer to a non-native speaker. Do you think the same would be true of 'chill'? It's very slangy and imprecise. So it warrants explanation that probably can't be extracted even tangentially from non-metaphorical dictionary definitions.

Comment: @Chappo Oh. Just read tmgr's answer. I would not have expected the 'full of nervous energy' in a published dictionary. I suppose looking things up _would_ have helped here. (_looks up_ chill)

Comment: @Chapo I dont agree with you, I used google translate and the translation makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the [*Oxford Living Dictionaries* definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/amp#amp-2) to start with:

> **amp** *(noun)*
>
> **short for amplifier**
>
> ---
>
> *(verb [with object])* ***often*** **amp something up**
>
> **play (music) through electric amplification**
>
> *Their willingness to amp up traditional songs virtually began the folk-rock genre.*
>
> ---
>
> *(as adjective)*  **amped** or **amped up** *(North American, informal)*
>
> **full of nervous energy**
>
> *Third-ranked Ohio State visits an amped-up Madison*

Based on this, for *amp* to denote some classification of music, I  see two possibilities:

First, **amped** could mean **amplified, i.e. not acoustic** - the normal definition of the verb given above. I think this is **unlikely**, for a number of reasons - it seems an odd classification for a website to make based on a playlist, and perhaps a difficult one to make too, but, mainly because *it isn't a 'mood'*.

*Plugged-in* or *electric* or *amped* in that sense doesn't fit with the other *'moods'* we can see in your screenshot: *danceable,* *chill* or *happy*.

Second, **amped** could mean **excited**, **pumped**, **hyped** - the adjectival definition given above - **full of nervous energy**.

This definition fits better in context with *danceable,* *chill* and *happy* and is **much more likely the intended meaning**. (For what it's worth, I don't think these *'moods'* seem to be a great classification system myself and I also think *amped* was quite a poor choice of name, given its ambiguity.)